# Cannot inspect webview on Safari

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ionic-framework

I am developing a new app using ionic with angular.
I realized that on devices with IOS 12, a component is not looking good, i want to inspect the html to see if the component now looks good.

I installed Safari technology preview for the testing, ran an iphone with ios 12, but safari does not recognize the simulated device. i tried restarting the computer, opening and closing the browser several times, changing the ios version but this hasn't worked yet.

I am using :
Xcode 12.5
Mac OS big sur 11.3.1
Safari technology preview :Release 124 (Safari 14.2, WebKit 16612.1.11.10)
Safari : Versión 14.1 (16611.1.21.161.6)

I saw this issue was happening like 4 years ago, and it was fixed buy restarting the computer, but this didn't work for me?
does somenone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Safari Technology Preview and now it's working perfectly.

I am able to inspect normally a review with it.

Hope it helps you too

Comment: @EricAya indeed, I should have left the note but it was the only solution I found here...